# How to specify a stretchable image with different left and right cap sizes on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uiimage

I'm implementing a drop down for iPhone.  The image looks like this:

[5px corners][1 px stretchable area][10px arrow with corners]

I'd like to use something like:

```
UIButton *dd = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];
dd.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[dd setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"dd"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5      topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I can't seem to find a way to specify the rightcapwidth.  The docs say it is calculated from the leftcapwidth.  There must be a way to have a stretchable image with different left and right fixed sizes?  Draw 9-patch image maybe?

Anyone have a solution for this on iphone?

Comment: Just add 5px of strechtable area in the middle, and change leftCap to 10px.

Comment: from the docs: rightCapWidth = image.size.width - (image.leftCapWidth + 1); So your image should just work

Comment: I have made a mistake before of having the image I want to stretch being wider that the final width I want on the button. This is stretchableImage not shrinkable image so your width (or height if distortion is vertical) is probably more than the final width of the button onto which you are setting the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next pixel after the leftcap is the only thing that is stretched horizontally. Therefore the 10 pixels on the right are preserved with their original size, and there is no point in having a right cap.

If there is any distortion on your image is due to something else. This should work:

```
UIButton *dd = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[dd setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];
[dd setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"dd.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:dd];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you would still see distortion is because the original image is wider than the width that you are specifying (or height if the distortion is vertical). E.g. if you want a button with a width of 200px but the original image is 300px wide you will see distortion even while using it as a stretchable image. Start off with a short image which can be stretched to whatever size you wish with the specified cap inserts e.g. an image with a width of 10px would work for your needs.